# Getting @section from multiple views in your layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code in my master.blade layout:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    
    @yield('loginpopup')
  
    <div id="content-component">
        @yield('content')
    </div>  
  
  </div>
```

This in my view, test-page.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div id="test-name"></div>
@endsection
```

This in my view, login-popup.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('loginpopup')
<div class="login_popup"></div>

@endsection
```

When I go to mywebsite.com/test-page, I only see the content from test-page.blade loaded correctly. How can I also load the content of popuplogin from login-popup.blade?

I want the login popup to be loaded on every page, without having to create the section in the views for each page.

Thanks.

Comment: Should login-popup.blade.php extend master?

Comment: @ka_lin Since the view comes from master layout, I'd think it should include that. But I could be wrong since I don't understand this very well yet.

Answer (score 0):

Include login-popup.blade.php in every page. You can do that by:

`@include('login-popup')`

Comment: I would prefer not to do that as I mentioned in my post. Is that the only way to get it to work?

Comment: There's actually a difference between @ include and @ section. But, yes @include is your best shot

Comment: So you mean I have to put @include('login-popup') in all my views?

Comment: Yes, pretty much that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- login-popup.blade.php will be added for every page when you call this master blade -->
  @include('login-popup')

  <div id="content-component">
      @yield('content')
  </div>  
</div>
```

in login popup page keep only html and remove blade's template code extends & section.

```
<div class="login_popup"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I could do that but I don't want the code for login_popup in the layout file. I would rather put it in a view. And since I am using react, it will go into a js file stemmed off from view.